# Wall of Fire - Do you end your turn near the wall if you damage the player that cast it and they lose concentration and the spell ends?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration

Player 1 casts Wall of Fire.  Enemy 1 is within 10 feet and fails their DEX save and takes the fire damage.  On Enemy 1's next turn they attack and damage Player 1 who fails the CON save to maintain concentration on the Wall of Fire spell.  Does Enemy 1 'end their turn' within 10 feet of the Wall of Fire if their attack ends the spell?  What is the timing?

Seems to me, since they could conceivably take a bonus action, their turn isn't over yet so the Wall of Fire spell ended prior to the end of their turn.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### If the spell ends during your turn, you cannot take damage from it at the end of your turn.

The rules for concentration state:

> Some spells require you to maintain concentration in order to keep their magic active. If you lose concentration, such a spell ends.

If your attack causes the target to lose concentration on the spell, the spell ends immediately, which is before the end of your turn. Since the spell ended before the end of your turn, it is not around to damage you at the end of your turn.

#### Your turn isn't over until you say it's over.

This is not explicitly stated in the rules, but there is always activity that can take place between using your action and the end of your turn. In the rules for "Your Turn", we see:

> **Other Activity on Your Turn**
>
> Your turn can include a variety of flourishes that require neither your action nor your move.
>
> You can communicate however you are able, through brief utterances and gestures, as you take your turn.

Since you could *always* do something included here after your action, your turn does not end until you decide there is nothing else you intend to do.

Comment: Alternatively: Your turn isn't over until the next person starts their turn (YMMV on how helpful that is though)